# addObject() in blender with python

Tags: python, object, dynamic, addition, blender

I ran into a little wall here:
my point is, for a empty, to move, then add a plane on the spot, then move, then add a plane etc, and then will end up with a 100X100 plain, so i scripted:

```
import bge

dunWidth = 100 #meters/tiles
dunHeight = 100 #meters/tiles
b = 0
a = 0
add= bge.logic.getCurrentScene().addObject

def main():
    global b, a
    cont = bge.logic.getCurrentController()
    dunMarker = cont.owner
    #Movement Calculation: (X, Y, Z)
    while b < dunWidth:
        b += 1
        add("FloorTile", "DunMarker",0)
        dunMarker.applyMovement((1,0,0), False)
        while a < dunHeight:
            add("FloorTile", "DunMarker",0)
            a += 1
            dunMarker.applyMovement((0,1,0), False)
        #dunMarker.applyMovement((0,-dunHeight,0), False)
main()
```

but instead, to my surprise, it First add the tile, then goes through the loop ignoring the add(), so the result is a 1x1 tile at 0x0y and the empty ends at 100x100y... how many things Im doing wrong here?Aaaand, since we are here, how would you improve the coding?(trying to learn here ;) )

pd, yeah, Roguelike 3D project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try positioning `dunMarker` with `worldPosition` you may also want to use for loops to get a grid instead of two edges.

```
import bge

dunWidth = 100 #meters/tiles
dunHeight = 100 #meters/tiles
a=0
b=0

add= bge.logic.getCurrentScene().addObject

def main():
    global a,b
    cont = bge.logic.getCurrentController()
    dunMarker = cont.owner
    for b in range(0,dunWidth,2):
        dunMarker.worldPosition=(b,a,0)
        t=add("FloorTile", "DunMarker",0)
        for a in range(0,dunHeight,2):
            dunMarker.worldPosition = (b,a,0)
            add("FloorTile", "DunMarker",0)
main()
```

Comment: thanks a lot!!! just a question, why when I set 1 instead of 2(to make an even floor of 100X100meters  takes 3 minutes to load and the framerate drops? but if I leave the increase to 2 goes without problem? (I made the tile 2x2 and works great)I guess you know why that happens since you set it to 2 instead XD

Comment: A default plane is 2.0 wide so I was positioning them to fit. The third number in `range()` is the step, using a step of 1 leads to four times as many planes created (100x100 vs 50x50). Adding lots of objects is known to be slow. Twice as many objects also means twice as many vertices and will be slower than one plane over the entire size. At 100x100 and 1.0 wide you are placing 10,000 objects with 40,000 vertices, while 50x50 at 2.0 wide is 2,500 objects with 10,000 vertices, the more data the slower it gets.